# How can we disable the SQl filter in Azure Subscriptions?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I use this to create my subscriptions :

```
public void CreateSubFilter(String TopicName, String SubscriptionName, String expression)
{

    var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
    // Create a filtered subscription
    SqlFilter MyFilter = new SqlFilter(expression);
    namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(TopicName, SubscriptionName, MyFilter);

}
```

I couldn't find the default Filter (Matchall) so `myFilter` is just Added to the match All Filter.
My question is how can I remove the Match all default Filter?

Edite 2 :
the Subscriptions Are working for something like proprty1 = 'value'
but it dont work when itry something with numbers like:
porpty1 > value
i read a lot about SQL filter and im sure that my probleme come from there ...
thanks for helping guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription has always a default rule (named "$Default") that contains a filter 1=1 (match all). 
AFAIK You need to call RemoveRule method on SubscriptionClient class.

Paolo.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to apply a filter then use the [CreateSubscription signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh330767.aspx) that doesn't take a filter. That won't apply the filter.

Comment: i want to apply a Filter 
but i have a default Filter (MatchAll) that rune My Filter because he take all the Messages
the question is how to remove the Match All filter

Answer (score 0):

thanks for ou help he is the Solution hope it will help :
to Create a Subsciption with a custum

```
public void CreateSubFilter(String TopicName, String SubscriptionName)
        { 
            var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(TopicName, SubscriptionName);

        }
```

the seconde one add the Filter and delete the default Filter (the match all ):

```
    public void addRuleFilter(String TopicName, String SubscriptionName, String filterName,String expression)
    {
           MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

        // Create a filtered subscription
        SqlFilter MyFilter = new SqlFilter(expression);

        SubscriptionClient mySubscriptionClient = factory.CreateSubscriptionClient(TopicName, SubscriptionName);
        try
        {
            mySubscriptionClient.RemoveRule("$Default");//delete  le MatchALL
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        mySubscriptionClient.AddRule(filterName, MyFilter);//add my Filter
    }
```

hope it help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add named RuleDescription:

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
// Create a filtered subscription
SqlFilter MyFilter = new SqlFilter(expression);
var ruleDescription = new RuleDescription("RuleName", MyFilter);
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(TopicName, SubscriptionName, ruleDescription);
```

In that case $Default rule won't created.